# launch4j JVM arguments relative path

Tags: java, launch4j

I have used launch4j to create a working .exe file for my java .jar application.

When I specify the absolute path everything works:

```
Djava.library.path=C:\Users\dre\Desktop\2014_11_24\Logfetch_v01_20141124\lib\rxtx-2.2pre2-bins\Windows\win64\
```

When I try to use relative paths:

```
-Djava.library.path=\lib\rxtx-2.2pre2-bins\Windows\win64\
-Djava.library.path=/lib/rxtx-2.2pre2-bins/Windows/win64/
```

The linking fails and parts of my app don't work.

I'm sure it's a silly mistake to do with \ and / due to my inexperience with the Windows OS.

Thank you.

Comment: `\lib\...` is really relative, well, it's relative to the root drive from where the program is executed...

Comment: Please could you explain further - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A relative path wouldn't start with a path separator, there is a difference between `lib\...` and `\lib\...`, which I'm pretty sure is the same for most OSs

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this JVM Option.

```
-Djava.library.path="%EXEDIR%\\lib\\rxtx-2.2pre2-bins\\Windows\\win64\\"
```